# How to show the json response values received from PHP file as jQuery autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: php, json, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using PHP, jQuery, AJAX, JSON, etc. for my website. I'm a newbie in AJAX,JSON and similar things. I'm implementing autocomplete functionality onto one textbox. I've written all the code for it, I'm getting the desired json response values based on the user input from PHP file but I'm not able to show this response as suggestions. Only the loader image keeps revolving and revolving. At the same time if I see into "Firebug Console's Response", I can see the proper response received from PHP file. For your reference I'm putting below the necessary code snippets from my code. Could anyone please guide me in displaying these recieved json response values as suggestions below autocomplete enabled textbox? For better understanding of my issue I've put a comment into jQuery code telling my actual issue.

The HTML and jQuery code is as follows:

```
<div class="form-element ui-widget">
  <input type="text" class="" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="{$user_name}"/>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
  $( "#user_name" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var class_id   = $('#class_id').val();
    var section_id = $('#section_id').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "report_student_result.php?op=get_student_names&class_id="+class_id+"&section_id="+section_id,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) { 


    /*Actually here I'm having a problem in displaying the json values properly
          Can you guide me in writing the json valus properly
          Forgive me if I've written something wrong below as I'm a newbie in json*/
        /*response( data, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item.full_name,
            value: item.full_name
          }
        });*/
          var autoCompleteDataSource = $.map(data, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.full_name,
            value: item.user_id
          }
        });
        $("#user_name").autoComplete({source: autoCompleteDataSource});
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {if(ui.item) { alert(event);
                 $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
             }
             return false;
  },
  open: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
  },
  close: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
  }
  });
});
```

Now the PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
  require_once("../../includes/application-header.php");
  prepare_request();
  $request     = empty( $_GET ) ? $_POST : $_GET ;
  global $gDb;
  $op = $request['op'];
  switch($op) {
    case'get_student_names':
      $param = $_GET["name_startsWith"];
      $group_id = $request['class_id'];

      if($request['section_id'] !='all')
        $group_id = $request['section_id'];

      if ($group_id != '') {
     $sql  =" SELECT u.user_id, CONCAT(u.user_first_name, ' ', u.user_last_name) as full_name ";
     $sql .=" FROM ".TBL_USERS." as u JOIN ".TBL_USERS_GROUPS_SUBSCRIBE." as ugs ON u.user_id = ";
     $sql .=" ugs.subscribe_user_id WHERE ugs.subscribe_group_id = ".$group_id." AND (u.user_first_name ";
     $sql .=" REGEXP '^$param' OR  u.user_last_name REGEXP '^$param')";
       } else {
     $sql  =" SELECT user_id, CONCAT(user_first_name, ' ', user_last_name) as full_name ";
     $sql .=" FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE user_first_name REGEXP '^$param' OR user_last_name ";
      $sql .=" REGEXP '^$param'";    
    }

    $gDb->Query( $sql );
    $data = $gDb->FetchArray(); 

    $response = json_encode($data);
    echo $response;

    die;        
  }
?>
```

And now the json response values displayed in firebug console's respinse menu, when I type in the word "ash":

```
[{"user_id":"324ded2773c6fadafb0d927addf815db","full_name":"Ashish katewa "},{"user_id":"4c11f67998e31610ff846e28896db538","full_name":"ashish kumar sharma "},{"user_id":"6dd8086fa23bad37580fe55f35509277","full_name":"ashok sharma "},{"user_id":"6ee2a24ca0b81e43100c70235822f48a","full_name":"ashish meena "},{"user_id":"7d15792ada9e5307288fa10cc62b36b9","full_name":"ashish "},{"user_id":"9a212d29e04391f271b924432c5d6c27","full_name":"ashish sharma"},{"user_id":"9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d","full_name":"Ashutosh Modi"},{"user_id":"ac074cfba36cddf865ead8bfe0dd2075","full_name":"ashish "},{"user_id":"aedcb718a9b4c9fc0a1aa5331956371a","full_name":"ashok jangir "},{"user_id":"d3c1ac9ac08da86e73258a11a43251af","full_name":"Ashok kumar mehra"}]
```

From the above response I want to show only the values from field full_name as suggestions. When user selects one of the suggested values I've to store the user_id associated with the selected user_name into hidden field. Can anyone help me in this regard?Thanks in advance.If you want any thing more about this question I can provide you the same.

Answer (score 0):

fair warning I don't have any knowledge about PHP, looking at you code and the result you have provided you can do the following to make the auto complete work.

```
success: function( data ) { 
    var autoCompleteDataSource = $.map(data, function( item ) {
        return {
            label: item.full_name,
            value: item.user_id
          }
    });
    $(selectorToAutoCompleteInpput).autoComplete({source: autoCompleteDataSource})
}
```

Comment: :I tried your trick but still the same issue persists. No suggestiond displaying at all.

Comment: Please find the working sample in [http://jsfiddle.net/k5fGG/], i have used your data so start typing any of the names and u will see the suggestions. If you are expecting the suggestion to be displayed onfocus on then un-comment the last three line in the sample.